# Using Interface Derived Classes with NEST and ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, interface, nest

I'm trying to use NEST 2.X and Elastic Search for persistent storage of Users. Each User contains a list of Roles which define their permissions inside our platform.

There are several different types of Roles each deriving from a IMediaDetectionRole interface:

```
public class MediaDetectionUser
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IMediaDetectionRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public MediaDetectionUser()
    {
        Roles = new List<IMediaDetectionRole>();
    }
}

public interface IMediaDetectionRole
{
    string Name { get; }
    string GetDescription();
    string GetRoleType {get;}
}

[ElasticsearchType(Name="MediaDetectionAdminRole")]
public class MediaDetectionAdminRole : IMediaDetectionRole
{        
    public string Name { get { return "Admin"; } }
    public string GetDescription() { return "Admin users can create other users within the account"; }
    public string GetRoleType { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
}

[ElasticsearchType(Name = "MediaDetectionManagerRole")]
public class MediaDetectionManagerRole : IMediaDetectionRole
{
    public string Name { get { return "Manager"; } }
    public string GetDescription() { return "Managers can modify account-level properties"; }
    public string GetRoleType { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
}

[ElasticsearchType(Name = "MediaDetectionCreatorRole")]
public class MediaDetectionCreatorRole : IMediaDetectionRole
{
    public string Name { get { return "Creator"; } }
    public string GetDescription() { return "Creators can create new Media Detection Profiles"; }
    public string GetRoleType { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
}
```

I don't have any trouble storing the data in ElasticSearch, but when I go to query the data the data NEST can't figure out the type of these roles. I get:

```
Could not create an instance of type IMediaDetectionRole. 
Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. 
Path 'hits.hits[0]._source.roles[0].name', line 1, position 343.
```

**What is the correct way to map nested object data back to the correct class type?**

Many thanks!

-Z

Comment: This exact use case is explained in the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/covariant-search-results.html :)

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I see how this would work for a top-level object. But these instances are part of a list within the MediaDetectionUser object. Its not clear to me how I would use either .Types() or a ConcreteTypeSelector to resolve the types of a nested object.

Comment: For your collection inside the DTO you could use [JsonPropery(ItemTypeHandling = TypeHandling.Objects], this will add $type to the serialized result and json.net will be able to deserialize it back into the correct class.

Comment: Aha! That's done it! 

I'll document my fix and post an answer here. I didn't understand that this issue was more on the JsonSerialization side then the NEST/ES side. As always, many thanks @MartijnLaarman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I guess this is less of a NEST/ES question and more of a JSON.NET question. Apparently the solution to this problem involves telling JSON.NET to provide type hints for each member of the list.

Per @MartijnLaarman's suggestion I added a [JsonProperty] attribute to the Roles property. See below:

```
public class MediaDetectionUser
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    //This JsonProperty helps reference the types during deserialization
    [JsonProperty("Roles", ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    public ICollection<IMediaDetectionRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public MediaDetectionUser()
    {
        Roles = new List<IMediaDetectionRole>();
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the JSON as it appears in the _source inside ElasticSearch:

```
Roles: [
  {
    $type: "MediaDetectionFrontend.ServiceModel.Types.MediaDetectionAdminRole, MediaDetectionFrontend.ServiceModel",
    name: "Admin",
    getRoleType: "MediaDetectionAdminRole"
  },
  {
    $type: "MediaDetectionFrontend.ServiceModel.Types.MediaDetectionCreatorRole, MediaDetectionFrontend.ServiceModel",
    name: "Creator",
    getRoleType: "MediaDetectionCreatorRole"
  },
  {
    $type: "MediaDetectionFrontend.ServiceModel.Types.MediaDetectionEditorRole, MediaDetectionFrontend.ServiceModel",
    name: "Editor",
    getRoleType: "MediaDetectionEditorRole"
  }
]
```

You can see that the $type attribute now provides the full type descriptor of each element in the List.

Big thanks to @MartijnLaarman who helped me solve this issue even though it really has nothing to do with ElasticSearch and NEST.